# Adding multiple css to Wordpress header.php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a few css files that need to be linked to the main PHP file for the slider, owl carousel plugin, etc.

After searcing, I found out how to add multiple css to my theme:

1) using `wp_register_style`
2)using `wp_enqueue_style`

I can't figure out the different between them. I also want to know how to use them.

this is my style links before I convert my HTML theme to Wordpress:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="stylecss/bootstrap.min.rtl.css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecss/bootstrap-3.2.rtl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecss/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font/stylesheet.css">
```

This is the way I try to link my css file:

```
<!-- adding bootstrap style sheet -->

<?php wp_register_style('bootstrap-style1',get_template_directory_uri() . '/stylecss/bootstrap.min.rtl.css.css',array(),'null', 'all', );?>

<?php wp_register_style('bootstrap-style2',get_template_directory_uri() . '/stylecss/bootstrap-3.2.rtl.css',array(),'null', 'all', );
?>

<!-- End of bootstrap style links -->
<!-- adding fonts style sheet -->

<?php wp_register_style('font-awesome',get_template_directory_uri() . 'fa/css/font-awesome.min.css',array(),'null', 'all', );
?>
<?php wp_register_style('fonts',get_template_directory_uri() . 'font/stylesheet.css',array(),'null', 'all', );
?>

<!-- End of fonts style links -->
```

What's the difference between adding this code to function.php and header.php? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093124/how-to-link-multiple-css-files-with-wordpress) that we can add both in header.php and function.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one of standard form to including css file in wordpress.

I put theme in function.php 
although I can't find what is the different between adding theme to function.php or header.php, not much different, just when you add theme in header.php is 't more flexible and you can cache more speed.

I use both of way one and two

```
wp_register_style('bootstrap-style1',get_template_directory_uri() . '/stylecss/bootstrap.min.rtl.css.css',array(),'null', 'all' );

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style1');
```

and if you want to know more about differences between this two way as I asked you can use this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/why-wp-register-style-is-important-while-im-using-a-complete-wp-enqueue-style) as Raunak Gupta told on his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add css in 2 ways, first you have to upload all the files in your active theme css directory, then you can either [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) or copy paste the below code to your active theme header.php file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.rtl.css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap-3.2.rtl.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font/stylesheet.css">
```

And for your 2nd question you can reffer to this [url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/why-wp-register-style-is-important-while-im-using-a-complete-wp-enqueue-style).

Comment: thank you for your helpful link. 
the standard way to adding css and js file as wordpress documentary (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) said is using wp_enqueue_style or script so I trying to write standard cods.

Comment: Yes, the use of `wp_enqueue_script` and  `wp_enqueue_style` is always recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference between wp_enqueue_* and respective wp_register_* functions, is that the first adds scripts/styles to the queue, the second prepares scripts/styles to be added.
More:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/why-wp-register-style-is-important-while-im-using-a-complete-wp-enqueue-style